# Faild to restart myapp correctly after compiling in pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm trying to build some code to restart.  Here is the problem. When I restart the app from source, the restart works fine. But, when I compile it, the code restart doesn't work properly. The following error appears:

```py
usage: MyApp [-h] [-c CONFIG] [-C CACHE] [-l LOG] [--devices] [--default-config]
MyApp: error: unrecognized arguments: /home/myapp/MyApp
```

But I'm not passing any args. In this case, the restart code is passing the path of the program which is, it shouldn't.
If I start the app, its starting fine. It's only on restart that there's a problem.
I'm using `debian11`, Python `3.9.2`. And pyinstaller `5.7.0`.
Here is my restart code.

```py
class RestartCommand(Command):
    @property
    def help(self) -> str:
        return "Restarts the app"

    def __call__(self, arg: str, user: User) -> Optional[str]:
        self._myapp.close()
        try:
            if 'frozen' in sys.builtin_module_names:
                executable = sys.executable
                if sys.platform == "win32":
                    subprocess.run([executable] + sys.argv[1:])
                else:
                    subprocess.run([executable, "-m", "__main__"] + sys.argv[1:])
            else:
                args = sys.argv
                if sys.platform == "win32":
                    subprocess.run([sys.executable] + args)
                else:
                    args.insert(0, sys.executable)
                    os.execv(sys.executable, args)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error while restarting: ", e)
```

I try to remove the argv like this.

```py
            if 'frozen' in sys.builtin_module_names:
                executable = sys.executable
                if sys.platform == "win32":
                    subprocess.run([executable])
                else:
                    subprocess.run([executable, "-m", "__main__"])
```

But, the same error still appears.
I try to read to documentation but found nothing.

Comment: your question is confusing... what is the purpose of the code and please post the full error message

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to create a restart code that can restart my app.
what should happen is, When I call the restart command, the code should just restart the app. But, The code does not work properly when it is compiled using pyinstaller. I didn't pass any arg but, it comes out.
"""
usage: MyApp [-h] [-c CONFIG] [-C CACHE] [-l LOG] [--devices] [--default-config] MyApp: error: unrecognized arguments: /home/myapp/MyApp
"""
When compiled, the restart code passes the program path which is, it shouldn't.
If not compiled, the code works normaly.

Comment: I still don't understand....  does your compiled application take command line arguments?... can you edit your question to include what you expect the subprocess command to look like based on what you are passing to the the command?